# Yii dataProvider change pagination link with no ajax pagination

Tags: php, yii

i try to change my   dataProvider  pagination link

Controller code:

```
public function actionOffers()
    {
        $this->layout='column2';
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('AmakenOffer');
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 15;

        $this->render('offers',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

my view :

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_viewoffers',
)); ?>
```

my url link :

```
http://localhost/11copy/index.php/site/offers?AmakenOffer_page=2
```

i need to change it for

```
http://localhost/11copy/index.php/site/offers?page=2
```

Comment: At least the ajax pagination part can be solved via `'ajaxUpdate'=>false,` in the view file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work:

```
$provider = CActiveDataProvider('model', array(
  'pagination' => array(
    'pageSize'=>15, 
    'pageVar' => 'page'
   )
));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#pageVar-detail

and ajax update part:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
 'ajaxUpdate' => false,
 'itemView'=>'_viewoffers', )); ?>
```

Comment: 'pageVar' => 'page'  is  true answer

Comment: i use  $dataProvider->pagination->pageVar = 'page';

Comment: can u help me in my question     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894995/yii-righs-module-redirect-to-another-page-if-user-not-authorized-not-403