# Yii rights module redirect to another page if user not authorized not 403

Tags: php, yii

i install rights module to my site
and i create controller called `ProfileController`

```
class ProfileController extends RController
{

    public function filters() 
    {
    return array('rights'); 
    } 
}
```

i  decided who can access this controller but when user try to access this page it redirect him to

```
Error 403
You are not authorized to perform this action.
```

i need in this case redirect to page  `PayDetails`

i try but fail in this case

Comment: What are you trying to say ? May be http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/ can help you or http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth?

Comment: i use rights module in yii ,, it works fine to me ,, i need to make user redirect to another page not Error 403 ..

Comment: Look up the default error handler in main.php and catch the error code in ErrorController.php and perform your action.

Comment: i have no error but after long search and no result  i need code like:  if user role access profile -> redirect to page 1   other page2  .. this is example only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution to my problem

first: you shold make role to your controller from your rights module 
like: access profile

second: i create index page any user can access it

```
public function allowedActions()
    {
    return 'index';
    }
```

third: i write this code in my index

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->layout='column2';
        $lang=Yii::app()->Language;
        $roles=Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app()->user->Id); // check for single role
            foreach($roles as $role)
            if($role->name == 'access profile')
            {
            $this->redirect(array('places'));
            }

        $this->render('index',array('lang'=>$lang));
    }
```

i think important part in this code

```
$roles=Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app()->user->Id); // check for single role
foreach($roles as $role)
if($role->name == 'access profile')
{
 $this->redirect(array('places'));
}
```